# Copy joomla folder - data is shared?

Tags: joomla

I installed joomla! 1.5 in a subfolder of my website root. Months later I decided to put the joomla site in the root folder, so I copied everything from the subfolder to the root folder. This worked, but I noticed something strange - the webite data is somehow shared between the two copies. For example, the visitors counter. When I click a few articles in my root joomla copy, I can see that the visitors counter has incremented. When I then enter my subfolder original installation of joomla, I see the counter showing the same value of the root folder copy of joomla. My questions are:
1. How is this happening, can I disable this connection between the two folders?
2. Suppose I choose to continue using the copy of joomla in the root folder without disconnecting the connection with the subfolder installation, am I going to encounter problems, or is it safe to just use the root folder copy?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both copies are using the same database. You'll start running in to issues once you have added any extensions that make changes to the database. There is no need for the old files, just delete them.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
(I also noticed that even a change to an article is reflected in both copies, which probably means that the articles themselves reside in the database and not as files in the file system...)

Comment: Yes, pretty much everything you do in the admin area (except the media manager, or installing extensions), is in the database.

Comment: Correct. Joomla separate the design (template files) from the functions (joomla core and extensions) and the content (database). This makes it easy to manipulate one of these without affecting the other 2.